# How do I make the game volume (not just voice/chat volume) come ONLY out of my headset and not my TV itself?

Tags: xbox-360

I recently purchased a Turtle Beaches Headset but it is one of those cheaper pair of Turtle Beaches (under $100). I can currently hear game and chat volume clearly out of my headset but I also realized that game volume also comes out of my TV. Since I like to turn up the volume when I play and I have roommates, whom I don't want to disturb, is there a way for the game volume to only come only out of my headset?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to alter this in the Xbox settings, but you could always just turn the TV volume all the way down, or on mute.  It shouldn't affect the headset (assuming the headset is the one connected to the controller).

Comment: hey PileOfDuty, your answer really helped me out a lot. I was able to mute my TV by just turning off the speakers in the TV settings. I lost the remote to my TV and my TV doesn't have an actual mute button on it so I had to actually just turn off the speakers. Anyways, it did the trick so thanks.

Comment: @user39616 You should mark this answer as accepted if it answers your question.